# Positioning element relative to another not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to position an element relative to another using the jQuery `offset()` method and I am trying to figure out why the `$(window).resize` function is not working.

JSBIN:http://jsbin.com/lanako/7/edit?html,js,output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<style>


div{
display:inline-block;
position:relative;
height:200px;
width:200px;
border:solid black;    
}

#somepara{
border: solid blue;
position:relative;
left:20%;
}

</style>
<body>
  <div id ="first"> FIRST</div>

  <div id = 'somepara'>  </div>


</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
var p = $( "#somepara" );
var pf =  $('#first');
var offset = p.offset();
p.html( "left: " + offset.left);

function offcss(){
pf.css({'left': offset.left + 6 + "px"});
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  offcss();
    $(window).resize(function(){
        offcss();
    });


});
```

I am essentially grabbing the `offset().left` of the second element `('#somepara')` and trying to set the css of  `('#first')` right 6 pixels from `(#somepara)`.Note: `(#somepara)` is has a fluid measurement (%), so the left position changes.

The equation initially works, but I want to upon resizing the browser, for the equation `pf.css()`, which calculates the css left property of `(#first)` to execute. Unfortunately the `$(window).resize` function I have set is not working, and thus the left property of `(#first)` is unchanged. The end goal I want is regardless the browser size, the elements will be separated by 6 pixels (`#first` right 6 pixels from `#somepara`).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The position of `#somepara` changes when you resize, so you need to take the value of `p.offset()` every time you call the `offcss()` function (and not only on first load).

```
function offcss() {
    pf.css({'left': p.offset().left + 6 + "px"});
}
```

Regarding the resize it seems like it does exactly what you want.

Check this example:
http://jsbin.com/dewazuyuqo/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thanks! Do you mind explaining why this works and mine doesn't? The variable offset replaced  p.offset(), otherwise it was exactly the same...

Comment: Your `offset` is a fixed value, while in my solution I'm getting the "current" value using the call to `p.offset()` (which changes every time you change the width of the window).